# Bash function not parsing arguments when in defined in variable

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm facing some strange behabiour in my bash script.

I have a simple script `parser.sh`, wich is really simple:

```
#!/bin/bash

for arg in "$@"
do 
    echo ARGUMENT: "$arg"
done
```

This script is called from another script in the same directory, lets call this one `test.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

`pwd`/parser.sh "ARG1=FIRST" "ARG2=TESTING SPACES"
```

The script shown above really works, and outputs the arguments as expected:

```
ARGUMENT: ARG1=FIRST
ARGUMENT: ARG2=TESTING SPACES
```

However, if I change the `test.sh` as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

ARGS="\"ARG1=FIRST\" \"ARG2=TESTING SPACES\""
`pwd`/parser.sh $ARGS
```

This simple modification, makes the code to fails when iterating over arguments:

```
ARGUMENT: "ARG1=FIRST"
ARGUMENT: "ARG2=TESTING
ARGUMENT: SPACES"
```

Why is that happening? What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can't think of any good reason to do what you are doing but you will find your answer in: [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

Comment: Read about word splitting and expansions in `man bash`.

Comment: *eval $PWD/parser.sh $ARGS*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't save your arguments in a regular variable, use an array:

```
args=( "ARG1=FIRST" "ARG2=TESTING SPACES" )
./parser.sh "${args[@]}"
```

Your quotes are being treated literally since they are escaped and your variable is being expanded without quotes so it is subject to word splitting.

Additionally there is no need to use `pwd` like that, `.` can be used to refer to the present directory.

You can see how your variable is being treated with the following:

```
$ ARGS="\"ARG1=FIRST\" \"ARG2=TESTING SPACES\""
$ printf '%q\n' $ARGS
\"ARG1=FIRST\"
\"ARG2=TESTING
SPACES\"
```

As you see the double quotes are expanding escaped which was not your intent, and the whitespace between `TESTING` and `SPACES` **is not** escaped.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help

Comment: One last question, I agree that it's a bad practise, but, why is happening that? I mean, I'm slipping away all the special characters, right?

Comment: @Manu: I have edited my answer

Comment: Thanks again, really apreciate it!